# Regex end when character appears

Tags: c#, regex

```
/index.php?option=com_phocagallery&view=category&id=54:jubilaci-2014&Itemid=57"><img src="/./images/phocagallery/jubilaci2014/thumbs/phoca_thumb_m_zbiorwka zbowice kopiowanie.jpg" alt="Jubilaci 2014" style="border:0" />

/index.php?option=com_phocagallery&view=category&id=52:obszar-funkcjonalny-kluczbork-namysw-olesno&Itemid=57"><img src="/./images/phocagallery/obszarfunkcjonalny/thumbs/phoca_thumb_m_dsc_1005retusz kopiowanie.jpg" alt="Obszar Funkcjonalny Kluczbork-Namysłów-Olesno" style="border:0" />

/index.php?option=com_phocagallery&view=category&id=39:szkolenie-z-obrony-cywilnej&Itemid=57" class="category">Szkolenie z Obrony Cywilnej
```

I get such list, and i want to get from this only link, like this:

```
/index.php?option=com_phocagallery&view=category&id=26:jubilaci-2011&Itemid=57
```

How can I do it using Regex? Maybe how to get everything before character, in my case it would be:

```
"
```

I have tried st like this:

```
.*">
```

But it doesn't work as i want to.

Comment: Are you dealing with valid HTML?  If so, just use a HTML parser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a solution without lookahead:

```
^[^"]+
```

- `^`: Start of the line,
- `[^"]`: all characters that are not double quotes,
- `+`: at least one those characters (*greedy* = as many as possible).

However, since you have tagged your question as C#, you could just split on `"` and take the first part -- no regular expression required:

```
var result = myString.Split('"')[0];
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a positive lookahead assertion.

```
@"(?m)^.*?(?="")"
```

It matches all the characters from the start upto the first `"` double quotes.

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/bS1zG7/3)